# using textfield value in executeUpdate

Tags: java, sql

How can we use textfield value in executeUpdate statement. I want to fetch data from a textfield and want to update database

Comment: StackOverflow is not a company you can hire to do your job. Post the code you have. Show that you have at least researched this and then, you will get help here

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes something like this:

```
TextField a = new TextField("defaultName");
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET NAME = ? WHERE ID = ?");
    pstmt.setString(1, a.getText());
    pstmt.setString(2, idOfEmployee);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Numbers in setString() means parameter number. 1 is first parameter in query, 2 is second...
More about this is in [documentation of PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: can i know what 1 denotes in pstmt